# How to create a list of recently expired domains?

Tags: database, dns, whois

I see many websites offering services to list recently expired domains. I also see many blogs on how to use these websites.

However, none of them explain what is necessary to generate the list in a computerized manner. Is it possible to do this without saving all the domain names and querying the whois to see if the registration is gone?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307553/possible-to-download-entire-whois-database-list-of-registered-domains/307590#307590).

Comment: [Domain squatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersquatting) and [Domain speculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_speculation). Bzip recently lost their domain to a squatter. Also see [Off-topic: what happended to bzip.org?](https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/36403427/) on the Valgrind mailing list.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33806/expired-domains-database

Answer (score 1):

Well, you wouldnt check every domain against whois every day. Instead, you would keep track of the expiration date of each domain from whois, and only check the domains that have expired to see if they have been renewed or not.

Comment: Do you have any more details to do this?

Comment: How would you generate the list of domains that you're checking? bruteforce? aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com aaaaaaaaaaaaaab.com ... ????

Answer (score 1):

[WhoisFreaks](https://whoisfreaks.com/) provides a systematic, well parsed, and normalized expiring domains Whois file in CSV format. You just have to download the file and can get all the domains that are expiring in the same column. No need to re-arrange the domains. You can download the expiring domains and their Whois information for those domains that are expiring 1 month after and 1 month before the current date.

There are three ways to get WhoisFreaks expiring domains file.

- You can download it directly from the billing dashboard manually.
- The latest generated file will be e-mailed to you.
- You can also get it thru an API endpoint.

You can see WhoisFreaks expiring domains whois sample file [here](https://files.whoisfreaks.com/v1.0//sample?fileType=expired).

Answer (score 0):

**Scraping of the Chinese expired domain trackers**

It is not pretty, but I've found the following trackers to contain valuable data:

- http://hupo.com, e.g.: [http://static.hupo.com/expdomain_myadmin/2013-01-01（国际域名）.txt](http://static.hupo.com/expdomain_myadmin/2013-01-01%EF%BC%88%E5%9B%BD%E9%99%85%E5%9F%9F%E5%90%8D%EF%BC%89.txt)
- https://webmasterhome.cn, e.g.: http://domain.webmasterhome.cn/com/2012-03-06.asp

Each year contains about 20 to 30 million expired domains.

I'm uploading my combined scraping of those websites to:

- https://archive.org/details/expired-domain-names-by-day as one zip per year for efficient download
- as a bunch of smaller uncompressed files for Google to index:

  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2011
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2012
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2013
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2014
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2015
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2016
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2017
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2018
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2019
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2020
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2021
  - https://github.com/cirosantilli/expired-domain-names-by-day-2022

Both of those sites contain the same data, except that each one has some URLs randomly missing, so they can complement one another relatively well.

Their first data point is 2011-07-29 as far as I could find, and the data seems to continue to the present.

Both are highly IP throttled, but can be scraped in about a week with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
dir=tmp/hupo
mkdir -p "$dir"
d="$(ls "$dir" | tail -n1)"
if [ -z "$d" ]; then
  # Smallest known working date:
  d=2011-07-29
else
  d="$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")"
fi
while [ "$d" != 2023-01-01 ]; do
  echo $d
  # Last known with space:
  # http://static.hupo.com/expdomain_myadmin/2012-01-23（国际域名）%20.txt
  # Earlist known without space:
  # http://static.hupo.com/expdomain_myadmin/2012-02-03（国际域名）.txt
  if [ "$d" \< 2012-02-03 ]; then
    space='%20'
  else
    space=''
  fi
  outfile="$dir/$d"
  set +e
  code="$(curl "http://static.hupo.com/expdomain_myadmin/$d（国际域名）${space}.txt" -o "$outfile" -w "%{http_code}")"
  stat=$?
  set -e
  if [ "$stat" -eq 0 ] && [ "$code" -eq 200 ]; then
    # Because of course they use CR LF, of course!
    # I kid you not ,some of them are invert sorted after some date.
    dos2unix "$outfile"
    sort -o "$outfile" "$outfile"
    echo sleep
    sleep 180
  else
    rm -f "$d"
  fi
  if [ "$stat" -eq 0 ]; then
    # Retry any potential network errors.
    d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
  fi
done
```

The webmasterhome.cn one is analogous.

I do not know their methodology, likely it is undocumented like most of this type of dataset, but I can give it the following characterization: it is not obtained through scraping alone. They must have had access [to something like a zone file](https://superuser.com/questions/24389/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-complete-zone-file-for-a-domain-without-contacting-its).

I know this because they contain several domain names which I'm very confident that the CIA used for their circa 2010 covert communication networks as I've documented at: https://cirosantilli.com/cia-2010-covert-communication-websites These are extremely likely therefore domains with no HTML backlinks to them, and must therefore have been obtained through other means.

I found these tracker websites by Googling for some of the CIA domains, and they were some the very few Google hits, among a few other non-Chinese trackers. Also, after scraping them, I was able to find other CIA websites, which further indicates that their data is real and valuable.

Further methodology and scripting described at: https://cirosantilli.com/cia-2010-covert-communication-websites/expired-domain-trackers